# conectar dos componentes con queryString en react

Tags: reactjs, querystring

tengan un excelente dia, me paso por aca para solicitar la ayuda de la comunidad, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano, tengo dos componentes en reactjs el cual no se conectan entre si de ninguna forma y necesito pasarle datos de un componente a otro con queryString, en un componente tengo diferentes deportes, debo clickear y en ese momento enviar la informacion del deporte clickeado a la pagina principal pero mainPage no es padre de sportPage, veo que con queryString se puede pero no se como implementarlo, como envio la informacion desde la sportPage y como lo recibo en mainPage con queryString?

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Es importante que tambien leas [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Has de explicar exactamente que quires hacer, qué has intentado y que problemas has tenido. sobre ellos podremos ayudarte.  Un saludo.

Comment: tendrias que emitir ese evento globalmente para que cualquier componente lo escuche, busca emit + react y si tienes problemas postea tu avance aqui mismo.

Comment: hola #lois6b muchas gracias por la sugerencia me hare le recorrido

Comment: gracias #x-rw intentare